# Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object in

Tags: php, fatal-error

i wrote this below code for my groups in my site..

```
public function set_group_id($group_id)
    {

        $db2        = & $this->network->db2;
        /* if( $this->id ) {
            return FALSE;
        } */
        if( ! $group_id ) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if( ! $g = $this->network->get_group_by_id($group_id) ) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        if( !$g->is_public && $this->user->id>0 && !$this->user->is_network_admin ) {
            $users  = $this->network->get_group_invited_members($g->id);
            if( !$users || !in_array(intval($this->user->id),$users) ) {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

         $D->i_am_network_admin  = ( $this->user->is_logged && $this->user->info->is_network_admin > 0 );
         $D->i_am_admin      = $D->i_am_network_admin;

         if( !$D->i_am_network_admin ) {
         $D->i_am_admin  = $db->fetch('SELECT id FROM groups_admins WHERE group_id="'.$g->id.'" AND user_id="'.$this->user->id.'" LIMIT 1') ? TRUE : FALSE;
         }


        if( $g->mojaz && !$this->user->i_am_admin  ) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $this->group    = $g;
        $this->to_user  = FALSE;
        return TRUE;
    }
```

my error in this line ...

```
             $D->i_am_admin  = $db->fetch('SELECT id FROM groups_admins WHERE group_id="'.$g->id.'" AND user_id="'.$this->user->id.'" LIMIT 1') ? TRUE : FALSE;
```

i want create limiter  for website groups if user is admin of site he can send a post
or if user is admin of group can send post else return false.

Answer (score 0):

In your error line $db is null, because **$db hadn't been declared in your function** set_group_id().
 I see only database object **$db2**

```
$db2 =& $this->network->db2
```

Try to replase $db to $db2. If $db2 contains correct database object and a handle to an open connection it will works